# splitting a string containing characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, split

I have the following string:

```
test = ['2*0', '4' , '3' , '2' , '3*8' , '4' , '5' , '6' ]
```

I am looking for a way to change the string to the below one:

```
final = ['0' , '0' , '4' , '3' , '2' , '8' , '8' , '8' , '4' , '5' , '6' ]
```

I dont know where to start with this one. do I need first to split those elements containing * and create a new string? any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use this simple technique :**

```
final=[]
for i in test:
    if "*" in i:
        a=[i.split("*")[1]]*int(i.split("*")[0])
        final.extend(a)
    else:
        final.append(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you find a `'*'` character, you can `str.split` on that, and pick apart the value and the number of times to repeat it. Then use `itertools.chain.from_iterable` to flatten the results into a list.

```
import itertools

def create_element(s):
    if '*' in s:
        rep, val = s.split('*')
        return [val for _ in range(int(rep))]
    return [s]

list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(create_element(i) for i in test))
```

Output

```
['0', '0', '4', '3', '2', '8', '8', '8', '4', '5', '6']
```

Answer (score 1):

One liner

```
[item for sublist in 
 [[s.split("*")[1]]*int(s.split("*")[0]) if "*" in s else s for s in test] 
 for item in sublist]
```

Comment: thanks for your solution. in this example that I just presented, your code works well. However, in my bigger list when I use it, the length is higher than my real length. I don't understand where the problem is in this code.

Comment: can you please post the sample where it is failing ?

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the list. When there's `*` in the element, split it and append the second element into the result the appropriate number of times.

```
def expand_list(l):
    result = []
    for s in l:
        if '*' in s:
            len, val = s.split('*')
            result.extend([val] * int(len))
        else:
            result.append(s)
    return result
```

Comment: `3*8` should give `'8', '8', '8'`, but this answer only gives a single `'8'`.

Comment: I didn't notice that.

Comment: worked very well both in this example and my bigger list. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
test = ['2*0', '4' , '3' , '2' , '3*8' , '4' , '5' , '6' ]
res = []
for i in test:
    if '*' in i:
            a,b = i.split('*')
            res.extend([b for i in range(int(a))])
    else:
            res.append(i)
# ['0', '0', '4', '3', '2', '8', '8', '8', '4', '5', '6']
```